# R Shiny: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable - no reactive

Tags: r, shiny

I know this question has been asked many times before, but most of those questions seem to be using 'reactive', which I am not using. I don't know whether I should be, I am very new to shiny. Reading some of the other posts I imagine that I should be dealing adding parentheses somewhere, but I don't know where to put them.

I have pasted my code below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

        selectizeInput(inputId = 'lsoa', 
                     label = 'Choose your lsoa', 
                     choices = c('Ealing' = 'ealing', 
                                 'Camden' = 'camden') , 
                     selected = 'camden', multiple = TRUE),
      uiOutput(outputId = 'tim')

    ),


    mainPanel(

      leafletOutput(outputId = "map")

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    l = leaflet(data = noise_lsoa) %>% 
      addTiles()%>%
      setView(lng = -0.083449, lat = 51.512573, zoom = 09)%>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~longitude, 
                 lat = ~latitude, 
                 popup = ~as.character(lpaeq_T), 
                 label = ~as.character(lsoa11nm))
      #addAwesomeMarkers(
      # lng=-0.4, lat=51.078039,
      #label='Testing additional labels',
      #icon = icon.glyphicon) %>%
    if (!is.null(input$lsoa)){

      l %>%

        addPolygons(data = subset(main_shape, grepl(paste(input$lsoa, collapse = '|'), 
                                                    tolower(lsoa11nm))), 
                    color = "#444444", 
                    weight = 1, 
                    smoothFactor = 0.5,
                    opacity = 1.0, 
                    fillOpacity = 0.5)
    }else {
      l
    }
    output$tim <- renderUI({
      minimum = min(noise_merge$full_date_time, na.rm = TRUE)
      maximum = max(noise_merge$full_date_time, na.rm = TRUE)

      sliderInput(inputId = 'time', label = 'Select your time',
                  min = minimum,
                  max = maximum,
                  value = minimum,
                  timeFormat = '%F %T')
    })
  })
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `render_` functions are reactive environments, and it is bad practice to nest render functions inside a render function. Try separating the `renderUI` and `renderleaflet`you may fix the problem.

Comment: Hi thanks, but what do you mean by separate renderUI and render leaflet? How would I separate them?

Comment: So you opened `renderLeaflet({` and before you close it with a subsequent `})` you use another render function `renderUI({`. This means that the `renderUI` is now inside the `renderLeaflet`  environment, which should be changed so that they are their own seperate environments.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you!